# tomcat is failing to start: SEVERE: Error starting static Resources

Tags: java, tomcat

I've been reading through all the existing answers and still cannot fix my problem.

1. I have an embedded tomcat instance it used to work *just fine*.
2. I even created a completely new install and it still breaks in the
   same way
3. I restarted my machine; in the vague hope that that would
   help.  it did not.
4. I am not skilled in configuration (I am getting
   better, though....)

how I start the server:

```
alias run-server='cd /Users/usingji/Code/sandbox/gcs/target/GlobalContentDelivery-Package/GlobalContentDelivery/; java -Dgcs.log.dir=/Users/usingji/mediaServer/log -Dgcs.home.dir=/Users/usingji/Code/sandbox/gcs/target/GlobalContentDelivery-Package/GlobalContentDelivery -jar GCS-v0.9.jar'
```

my error:

```
   0:36:45,083 INFO  [PropertyUtil] Loading Property file
10:36:45,084 INFO  [PropertyUtil] Loading Property file
10:36:45,085 INFO  [ServerLauncher] webPort is 8080
10:36:45,085 INFO  [ServerLauncher] web root is webapp 
10:36:45,091 INFO  [ServerLauncher] base path: /Users/usingji/Code/sandbox/gcs/target/GlobalContentDelivery-Package/GlobalContentDelivery
10:36:45,092 INFO  [ServerLauncher] just set the port
10:36:45,092 INFO  [ServerLauncher] config name: webapp 
10:36:45,092 INFO  [ServerLauncher] file: ackack: /Users/usingji/Code/sandbox/gcs/target/GlobalContentDelivery-Package/GlobalContentDelivery/webapp 
10:36:45,092 INFO  [ServerLauncher] absolute path: /Users/usingji/Code/sandbox/gcs/target/GlobalContentDelivery-Package/GlobalContentDelivery/webapp 
10:36:45,175 INFO  [ServerLauncher] configuring app with basedir: /Users/usingji/Code/sandbox/gcs/target/GlobalContentDelivery-Package/GlobalContentDelivery/webapp 
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /Users/usingji/Code/sandbox/gcs/target/GlobalContentDelivery-Package/GlobalContentDelivery/webapp  does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Jan 22, 2014 10:36:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 22, 2014 10:36:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
10:36:46,227 INFO  [ServerLauncher] Starting Tomcast ...
```

the webapp dir does exist:

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 usingji  PEROOT\Domain Users    204 Jan 22 10:34 webapp
```

Code that starts the tomcat instance:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // load all the default configs files
        loadDefaults();

        // // port number
        String webPort;
        webPort = System.getProperty("gcs.web.port");
        if (webPort == null) {
            webPort = System.getenv("gcs.web.port");
        }
        if (webPort == null) {
            webPort = PropertyUtil.getValue(Constants.PORT_CONFIG_NAME);
        }
        log.info("webPort is " + webPort);
        String webappDirLocation = PropertyUtil.getValue(Constants.WEBAPP_CONFIG_NAME);
        log.info("web root is " + webappDirLocation);
        tomcat = new Tomcat();
        String basePath = FileUtil.getBasePath();
        log.info("base path: " + basePath);
        tomcat.setBaseDir(basePath);
        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
        log.info("just set the port");

        String configName= PropertyUtil.getValue(Constants.WEBAPP_CONFIG_NAME);
        log.info("config name: "+ configName);
        File ackack = new File(basePath,configName);
        log.info("file: ackack: " + ackack);
       String absPath  = ackack.getAbsolutePath();
       log.info("absolute path: " + absPath);
        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp(
                "/",
                absPath);
        ctx.setDefaultWebXml(new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath()
                + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");

        // unzip folder location
        tomcat.addWebapp(PropertyUtil.getValue(Constants.EXPORT_URL_PATH),
                PropertyUtil.getValue(Constants.PXE_UNZIP_FOLDER));

        log.info("configuring app with basedir: "
                + new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        tomcat.start();
        log.info("Starting Tomcast ...");
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the config file that had the link to the folder (webapp) had either a space or an invisible control character after the name of the file.

I found this out by:

1. reverting to an earlier version of the code that worked

   my coworkers
       mentioning that they had the same problem and that fixing the config
       file fixed it

   I then diffed the non-working config file with the working file and found the problem

so frustrating and insidious!  I'm glad that is now solved and done!

Comment: I am having a similar problem. What do you mean by "config file" in this context please?

Comment: there should be a properties file that is used for configuration